# Android onDraw() executing on all Views?

Tags: android, custom-view, ondraw

Here is a weird behavior that I don't understand about custom views. I have two views in a frame layout, one on top of the other. The views are simple and I've made them just for a short test

```
public class View1  extends View  {
....

    @Override
     public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            this.updateDrawings();
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if (canvas != null) 
        {
            Log.i("Test", "Draw View1");
        }
    }

    public void updateDrawings() {
        try {
            this.invalidate();
        }
        finally {
        }
    }
}
```

and View2

```
public class View2  extends View  {
....

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if (canvas != null) 
        {
            Log.i("Test", "Draw View2");
        }
    }

    public void updateDrawings() {
        try {
            this.invalidate();
        }
        finally {
        }
    }
}
```

Everything well packed on a FrameLayout

```
<FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffffff">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <com.View2
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dip" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <com.View1
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dip" />
        </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

My question is: why when onTouch executes from View1, both view's onDraw() method executes ? Why not only View1's ?

**Later Edit**  View2 has a big image to draw, the image is rotated and scaled according to some saved preferences. Normally, when I start the Activity, the View2.onDraw() takes care of rotating, translating and scaling of the Bitmap and draw it on canvas. When the user touches View1 I want only View1.onDraw() to execute because there's no point to redraw the same background image over and over again for each user interaction. How can I stop View2.onDraw() to execute ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should answer your question:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewParent.html#requestLayout()

"Called when something has changed which has invalidated the layout of a child of this view parent. This will schedule a layout pass of the view tree."

Comment: I have edited the question a little. Pleare read the Later edit section, maybe you have an idea. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Have you tried calling draw in View1, instead of updateDrawings? Don't know what will happen though.

Comment: I'm currently testing setWillNotDraw(true) to see if stops sending invalidate forward.

Comment: setWillNotDraw will stop view drawing, but in this case the background image is missing...

Comment: Is it because you called setWillNotDraw(true) in the constructor or anything?

Comment: Well, actually it seems  that when a view invalidates and sends the invalidate to rest of the views in the three, if a view has setWillNotDraw(true) the result is that when the view get's invalidate simply doesn't redraw and remains empty. This is usefull when you don't want background views that are not visibible to redraw.